# Serial Interfacing of Arduino with Raspberry Pi to transmit 2 digit data

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi3, pyserial

```
/*
  String to Integer conversion

 Reads a serial input string until it sees a newline, then converts
 the string to a number if the characters are digits.

 The circuit:
 No external components needed.

 created 29 Nov 2010
 by Tom Igoe

 This example code is in the public domain.
 */
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(23, 22,13,12,11,10);
String inString = "";    // string to hold input

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(19200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
    lcd.begin(20, 4);

  // send an intro:
  //println("\n\nString toInt():");
  //Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  // Read serial input:
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
    lcd.print("welcome");
    int inChar = Serial.read();
    if (isDigit(inChar)) {
      // convert the incoming byte to a char
      // and add it to the string:
      inString += (char)inChar;
    }
    // if you get a newline, print the string,
    // then the string's value:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      int data = inString.toInt() ;
      lcd.setCursor(0,1); 
      lcd.print("speed: ");
      lcd.println(data);
      if(data > 50){
        lcd.setCursor(0,2); 
        lcd.print("Over speed");
      }
      else{
        lcd.setCursor(0,2); 
        lcd.print("Under speed limit ");
      }

     // Serial.print("Value:");
      //Serial.println(inString.toInt());
      //Serial.print("String: ");
      //Serial.println(inString);
      // clear the string for new input:
      inString = "";
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Python code for serial interfacing]

This code works while using serial monitor with Arduino, but when run interface Arduino with Raspberry Pi, only "welcome" message come on LCD not data (2 digit number) that I transferred through Raspberry Pi, may be it is due to Python program on Raspberry Pi or any other reason.

Comment: Did you seriously just took a photo of a screen, instead of just simply copy pasting the code? Why?

Comment: Because I can't copy paste python code from R pi to my laptop =D ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking for "\n" but never sending one. so you'll never trigger

if (inChar == '\n')

Comment: Thanks . I just solved this issue after posting question here  , like you are saying that was problem ..

Comment: Need some help , I will be thankful to you 
'speed = "70\r\n"
arduino.write(speed)'
This code works fine and gives out put at LCD on arduino like
 "speed = 70
   Over speed"
But when I use this statement 
' speed = 70 
 arduino.write("speed\r\n")'
It will show 
" speed =0 
Underspeed limit" on LCD.why ? I am doing this for speed limit monitoring system , when that code find speed it store in "lastlimit"
arduino.write("lastlimit\r\n") gives above issue ..I am not much familiar with python ,  i tried but did't find any solution

Comment: arduino.write("speed\r\n")'  will write the literal string "speed\r\n" not "70\r\n" you need to write (speed +"\r\n").  Or more likely  (str(speed) +"\r\n") as speed is an int.  does that help? if not please post a new question and let me know